# Express typescript error Error: Access denied for user ''@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, typescript, express, yarnpkg

so according to Express file architecture i have a file named database.ts and it's working fine.Also i'm using mysql DB, however when i tried to make routes for the database it won't connecct to mysql server on docker.

**database.ts**

```
import * as mysql2 from 'mysql2';
import * as process from 'process';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { channel } from 'diagnostics_channel';

dotenv.config();

const pool = mysql2.createPool({
    host: process.env["MYSQL_HOST"],
    user: process.env["MYSQL_USER"],
    password: process.env["MYSQL_PASSWWORD"],
    database: process.env["MYSQL_DATABASE"]
}).promise();


export async function getusers() {
    try {
        const [rows] = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users");
        return rows; // Return the retrieved rows
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', err);
        throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it elsewhere if needed
    }
};

export async function get_user_by_ID(id: number) {
    try {
        const [rows] = await pool.query<mysql2.RowDataPacket[]>("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", [id]);
        return rows[0]; // Return the retrieved rows
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching users by ID:', err);
        throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it elsewhere if needed
    }
};

async function getchannels(id: number) {
    try{
        const [rows] = await pool.query<mysql2.RowDataPacket[]>("SELECT * FROM channels WHERE channel_id = ? ", [id]);
        return rows[0];
    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Error fetching channels :', err);
        throw err;
    }
}

async function getmssages(id: number) {
    try{
        const [rows] = await pool.query<mysql2.RowDataPacket[]>("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id = ?", [id]);
        return rows[0];
    } catch (err){
        console.log("Error fetching messages: ",err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

**users.ts**
**Note: This file includes the route for users db**

```
import { Router, Request, Response, } from "express";
import { getusers, get_user_by_ID } from "../config/database";
import dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config()

export const UsersRouter: Router = Router();

UsersRouter.get("/users", async (req: Request, res: Response)=>{
try{
    const userlist = await getusers();
    res.json(userlist);
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Cannot get users: ", err);
}
});

UsersRouter.get("/users/:id", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const userId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    try {
        const user = await get_user_by_ID(userId);
        if (!user) {
            // User with the specified ID not found
            return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
        }
        res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't get user by ID: ", err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

async function get_user_roles() {
    try{
        const  [rows] = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM user_roles");
        return rows
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error fetching user roles: ",err)
    }
}

async function get_use_role_assignment() {
    try{
        const [rows] = await pool.query("SELECT * from user_role_assignment");
        return rows
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error fetching user role assingment: ", err)
    }
}

// fetching users
export const users = async () => {
    return await getusers();
};

(async () => {
    console.log(await users());
})();

// fetching user by id
 export const user_by_id = async (id:number) =>{
    return await get_user_by_ID(1);
 };

 (async () =>{
    console.log(await user_by_id(1))
 })();

 // fetching channels
 export const channels = async () =>{
    return await getchannels(1);
 };
(async () =>{
    console.log(await channels());
})();

 // fetching messages
 export const messages = async () =>{
    return await getmssages(1);
 };
 (async () =>{
    console.log( await messages());
 })();
```

P.S: i tried running the database.ts in config file and it worked established a connection succesfully and fetched the data, however it won't connect in the users.ts, note that the users.ts is in the routes dir i don't know if it has anything to do with the dirs

Comment: Please share more details. Shouldn't you use a proper hostname for the Docker container? Did you modify the port? And how is this problem related to [tag:yarnpkg]?

Comment: what info do you need? i also said before that i established connection succesfully before in the database.ts but i don't know whty it won't connect also i noticed in the error log that it want to connect with the ip assigned to it which is "172.18.0.2" but i already assigned the default local ip adderss with the credentials in an .env  file but the users.ts is somehow wants to use the default ip adderss, and doesn't see the credentials in an env file as it's provided in another dir, also i tried creating the same .env file and imported it but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What does `process.env["MYSQL_HOST"]` contain, and how does your Docker configuration for the database container look like

Comment: i don't get what do you mean by db container configuration look like? i can edit the question and post a docker-compose file if that's what you need. also the process.env is a module that i downloaded and is used with .env file which will have my db credentials, so it won't be hard coded and safer.

Comment: I still assume that `MYSQL_HOST` does not contain the proper hostname to your database

Comment: MYSQL_HOST doesn't store a name it stores the IP adders of the container which is local in my case and any local machine, or docker image would typically have the IP of 127.0.0.1,

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. If your MySQL server runs in a Docker container, you should most probably check the IP (better a hostname) and the port it uses. `docker ps` could help to see which configuration is **actually** used